# Move to segmentedview with second tab visible

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm trying to navigate to a segmented view with 2 tabs / views and the second tab / view must be visible. 
With the folowing code I can move to the segmented view but the first tab is visible. I also tried with a Segue but than my navigation in the footer and header disappears..

```
let mainViewController: UITabBarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainController") as UITabBarController;
        mainViewController.selectedIndex = 1;
        self.presentViewController(mainViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not correct. Try this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {         
    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1     
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this redirect me to the segmentedview but I want the second segment visible. By default the first segment is always visible and when you click on the second tab the second will be visible and the first hidden. How can I set the selectedSegmentIndex to 2 before the redirect?

Comment: you must put it in the viewWillApear of the second controller. Can't make a UI change before the UI has been created.